# Переход к фоновому процессу в Linux

Tags: linux

Создал фоновый процесс с помощью команды **setsid**. Можно ли как-нибудь вывести его на передний план(подобно тому как это можно сделать с некоторыми процессами в текущей сессии используя команду **fg**)? Можно ли так сделать со всеми процессами зная их *PID* или *SID*?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31478730/4827341